# pom-only artifact unexpectedly deployed as jar to Artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, artifactory

I have a multi-module project with a root `pom.xml`, defined with `<packaging>pom</packaging>`, and several `<modules>`.

On Jenkins, I run maven with the goals `jar:jar install:install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` (compiling and testing was already done by previous jobs in the build pipeline).

As a post-build action, I deploy artifacts to Artifactory. I checked 'Deploy Maven artifacts' and left include/exclude blank so it will take the defaults.

The submodules correctly have their pom and jar deployed to Artifactory. I see this in the console output:

```
Deploying artifacts of module: com.example:foo
Deploying artifact: https://repo.example.com/snapshot/com/example/foo/7.0.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Deploying artifact: https://repo.example.com/snapshot/com/example/foo/7.0.0-SNAPSHOT/foo-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

The `root` pom is not correctly uploaded to Artifactory.

When "Supress POM Consistency Checks" is **off**, the build fails with a conflict on the `root` pom:

```
Deploying artifacts of module: com.example:root
Deploying artifact: https://repo.example.com/snapshot/com/example/root/7.0.0-SNAPSHOT/root-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
ERROR: Failed to deploy file: HTTP response code: 409. HTTP response message: Conflict
java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file: HTTP response code: 409. HTTP response message: Conflict
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.throwHttpIOException(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:743)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:623)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:329)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.maven2.ArtifactsDeployer.deployArtifact(ArtifactsDeployer.java:190)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.maven2.ArtifactsDeployer.deploy(ArtifactsDeployer.java:130)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.ArtifactoryRedeployPublisher.perform(ArtifactoryRedeployPublisher.java:420)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1047)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Deploy artifacts to Artifactory' changed build result to FAILURE
```

When "Supress POM Consistency Checks" is **on**, I check `root` on Artifactory and I go to "POM View", then I see binary garble starting with "PK", which indicates a ZIP file or in this case probably a JAR file. Downloading that file and extracting as zip confirmed that it contains a `META-INF` directory with some subdirectories related to Maven.

What I was expecting, was a plain text `pom.xml` for `root`.

I also noticed this in the console log:

```
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/example-develop-maven-artifactory/workspace/target/example-root-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to com.example/root/7.0.0-SNAPSHOT/root-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

and then

```
Deploying artifacts of module: com.example:root
Deploying artifact: https://repo.example.com/snapshot/com/example/root/7.0.0-SNAPSHOT/root-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Deploying artifact: https://repo.example.com/snapshot/com/example/root/7.0.0-SNAPSHOT/root-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

As I understand it, Artifactory intercepts what the build tool deploys in the local repository (`~/.m2`).

How do I get the pom, and only the pom, and no magically generated jar, of my `root`, on Artifactory? Which probably boils down to, how do I tell Maven and/or Jenkins not to overwrite my `root` pom with a `root` jar?

Versions:

- Artifactory 3.4.2 (rev. 30140)
- Jenkins 1.643
- Artifactory Plugin 2.4.7

Comment: Why do you do: `jar:jar install:install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` instead of `mvn clean install`  or if you like to deploy those artifacts to repo manager just use `mvn clean deploy` ?

Comment: That question is already answered in the second line of my question: a previous build job in the pipeline executed the other goals. To get into detail, just running `jar:jar install:install` takes 45 seconds, while `clean install` takes 4.5 minutes, with tests skipped (and 25 minutes with tests).

Comment: Why separating the the steps, cause just do a deploy in the previous pipeline step? Or use Jenkins to do the deployment instead of Maven..?

Comment: Sorry, there is a language barrier. I am not a native English speaker. I do not understand your comment. Please explain.

Comment: try "mvn deploy -N" this will deploy only the parent pom not the modules

Comment: Now I am doing `install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dcheckstyle.skip=true -Dfindbugs.skip=true` which takes 59 seconds, compared to 45 seconds before. What I do not like about this, is that `install` also does all previous steps of the Maven lifecycle, which is a complete waste of time because the upstream job already did the `compile` phase in the same workspace.

Comment: @Hishamkh I want to deploy the parent pom **and** the modules.

Comment: i think the magically generated jar of the root is forced by the jar:jar command. (this ignoring the pom packaging nature of your artifact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from @khmarbaise's comment, I am now running the build with

```
mvn install \
    -Dmaven.main.skip=true \
    -Dcheckstyle.skip=true \
    -Dfindbugs.skip=true \
    -Dmaven.test.skip=true \
    -Dmaven.site.skip=true \
    -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

The build still takes 54 seconds, which is unfortunate, but there isn't *Yet Another Redundant Compilation*, which is exactly what I want.

The pom-only `root` is correctly deploted to Artifactory.